# Openstack with conjure-up and MAAS

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack, juju

I'm trying to deploy a muli-node Openstack KVM cluster using conjure-up and MAAS.
I'm following this tutorial: https://www.ubuntu.com/openstack/install#cluster-deployment

I configured everything as specified. I have 6 servers: 1 for MAAS-controller, 1 for juju controller and 4 to deploy openstack.

conjure-up succeed to deploy the juju-controller and another server with Ubuntu 18 LTS, but all the others 3 servers fail with the following error:
[image]
[image: image1]

[Full log of Ubuntu 18 LTS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/023iehicd38dt57/star-worker-1.logs.txt?dl=0)
[Full log of Failed Deployment Node](https://www.dropbox.com/s/umkcphp921usy6w/star-worker-2.logs.txt?dl=0)

I haven't changed the default configuration of conjure-up (3 ceph-mon, 3 ceph-osd, 3 nova-compute). 
Are 6 servers enough for this configuration?

I've tried also to change everything to 1 (1 ceph-mon, 1 ceph osd, 1 nova-compute) but I had the following errors:
[image]

Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I configured the RAID 0 on the servers in the BIOS.
I removed the configuration, configured the RAID in MAAS for each node and restart the deployment and now it is working